# Connecting uDig with Sql server 2008

Tags: sql-server, udig

I tried to connect uDig with Sql server 2008 but could not do it the following error poped that it missed imageio ext and jdbc driver for sql server. I added it to jre/ext/lib (both of them). Now the error is not present but when I click next and click finish there is no change.What is the Error in here?
[image]

Comment: Namespace is required - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2553515/sqlservernamespaces-preventing-access-to-query-data

Comment: @Mapperz how do I provide namespace?